# Wrong time when not connected to Internet

Tags: 20.04, time

I have been a couple of days without Internet at home as my router has died. During these days I have observed the time shown by Ubuntu was completely wrong, way off.

I do not think this is normal and I would like to fix it in case I need to travel or use the laptop without Internet connection.

Does anyone know how to do that?

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I have Windows as well installed, however I have not used it during this time.

I have configured Ubuntu to use local time rather than UTC so it does not conflict with Windows in case I use it.

Thank you in advance and regards.

Comment: tried timedatectl set-ntp true ?  (If someone spotting a error in this comment please point that out!)  Regards.

Comment: you said "it is completely new"... did you set the clock in your bios to the correct time?

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is old (5-10 years), cmos battery may be dead.
Check in the bios settings if time is correct if it's not, change cmos battery.

Comment: It is completely new.

Answer (score 0):

1. Figure out the long name of your timezone (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/DateTime::TimeZone::Catalog.3pm.html)
2. echo "TIMEZONELONGNAME" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
3. sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

And that should do it!

Comment: Thanks! This is only to set the time zone, isn't it? I had that already set

Comment: Hmmm, I see. So is it a graphical error? Because if you have the timezone set properly then it should show you the correct time whether or not your connected to the internet.

Comment: What kind of laptop is it?

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted the CMOS  comment - likely to be a cause.

If you are travelling and establish a wifi connection, the NTP (network time protocol) will correct the clock for you.
If your laptop is drifting the reality is that unless it is old, it is unlikely you will be able to find and replace a battery on the motherboard - they are rarely designed to do that now.

Short version : don't worry - it will sort itself out when wifi available locally or remotely.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 uses `systemd-timesyncd` and not `ntpd` to handle getting the time from time-servers on the network.  (However, it still uses the NTP protocol).

You can check the daemon is running

```
ps -aux | grep systemd-timesyncd
```

and you can check on the daemon status with

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
```

which for me returned

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-10-16 20:23:33 PDT; 1 day 5h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 1137 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9313)
     Memory: 2.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─1137 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Oct 16 20:23:33 system-999-9999 systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Oct 16 20:23:33 system-999-9999 systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Oct 16 20:24:04 system-999-9999 systemd-timesyncd[1137]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

If there is some error it should appear in the status.  If you haven't connected for a while that might appear as an error.